# Display JSON with ng-repeat with some conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this JSON file that I used `$http()` to get. It is something like this:

```
[{
    "sno": "4",
    "eventname": "cricket",
    "event-type": "sports",
    "A-team": "mme",
    "B-team": "eee",
    "Gender": "male",
    "time": "2017-11-24 00:00:00",
    "isresult": "1",
    "result": "[{\"a\":\"121/5\",\"b\":\"122/4\"}]",
    "match-type": "semi",
    "venue": "downs"
},
{
    "sno": "2",
    "eventname": "cricket",
    "event-type": "sports",
    "A-team": "cse",
    "B-team": "mme",
    "Gender": "female",
    "time": "2017-11-17 00:00:00",
    "isresult": "0",
    "result": "winner team-a",
    "match-type": "league",
    "venue": "tsg"
}]
```

I need to display this using `ng-repeat` but display `{{item.result}}` only when its property (boolean) `isresult` is `0`. If `isresult === 1` and `event-type=='sports'`, I have that array which I need to `ng-repeat`.

I did something like this:

```
<th ng-if="item.isresult === 1 && item[event-type] === 'sports'">
   <div ng-repeat="i in item.result">
      {{i.a}}<br>{{i.b}}
   </div>
</th>
```

Further, if `event-type === 'athletics'`, I get the `result` in an array which looks like `[{"1":"Xjdjd"}, {"2":"Jxjxj"}, {"3":"Dhdj"}]`

How do I go about it?

Comment: You can create a helper method that checks for when `isResult ===  1`, this method would return the array if it exist then in your `ng-repeat` you would call the method and loop over it.

Comment: Could you make a simple fiddle to explain it?

Comment: To do this I'd have to see the full code.

Comment: You can filter isResult === 1 only from your api, then you can pass the data to controller to get that data in front end, will you post your api code here? i will help you to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
      "event-type": "sports",
      "isresult": "1",
      "result": [{
        "a": "121/5",
        "b": "122/4"
      }],
    },
    {
      "event-type": "sports",
      "isresult": "0",
      "result": "winner team-a",
    },
    {
      "event-type": "athletics",
      "isresult": "1",
      "result": [{
        '1': 'Xjdjd'
      }, {
        '2': 'Jxjxj'
      }, {
        '3': 'Dhdj'
      }],
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='item in data'>
    <div ng-if="item.isresult == 1 && item['event-type'] === 'sports'">
      <div ng-repeat="i in item.result">
        {{i.a}}<br>{{i.b}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item.isresult == 0">
      {{item.result}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item['event-type'] === 'athletics'">
      <div ng-repeat="i in item.result">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in i">
          {{key}}:{{value}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr ng-if='!$last'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if I understood your problem correctly:

```
<th>
   <div ng-if="item.isresult=='0'">{{item.result}}</div>
   <div ng-if="item.isresult=='1' && item[event-type]=='sports'" ng-repeat="i in item.result">
      {{i.a}}<br>{{i.b}}
   </div>
</th>
```

Keep in mind, your `result` in **JSON** object suppose to **Array** only, it looks like **String** for `item.isresult=='1'` also. so check this or **parse** it into an Array.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from answers of others.

I've made a function that sorting that values.

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/sg4xscku/4/)

Below is function that sorting value of item.

```
$scope.sortIsResult = function(item){
    var result = '';
    if(item.isresult==='0'){
        result = item.result;
    } else if (item.isresult==='1') {
        if(item['event-type'].trim()==='sports'){
            result = 'a:' + JSON.parse(item.result)[0]['a'] + '\n' 
                    + 'b:' + JSON.parse(item.result)[0]['b'];
        } else if(item['event-type'].trim()==='athletics'){
            result = '1:' + JSON.parse(item.result)[0]['1'] + '\n' 
                    + '2:' + JSON.parse(item.result)[1]['2'] + '\n'
                    + '3:' + JSON.parse(item.result)[2]['3'];
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Maybe this seems like dizzy, but I think there's limitation by using 'ng-if',

So I like to use function.

I hope this can be a little helpful for you. :)

Unfortunately, '\n' of this function did not work.

Maybe you'll need other way to make line breaking.